# Need help figuring out why my UIImageView won't Zoom/Pan - Code snippet included

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, xamarin.ios

I have put a lot of code in place to try to get a UIImageView to Zoom/Pan.  In the code below I have a large scrollView with paging and in each page I put in a scrollView which contains an imageView that I want to be able to Pan and Zoom.  I've read many articles and still can't get the zooming and panning to work.  Maybe an expert could help me figure out what I am missing.  I am new to iOS/MonoTouch development.

One thing to note is that my DidZoom (scrollViewDidZoom) delegate is not being hit when I put a breakpoint.  ZoomingStarted is being hit, but it's not the delegate I need.

```
//TODO: Code to put here to load image or whateer you want to display on this panel/page

    //Each page will have it's own scrollview for scrolling and zooming that image on the page
    var panelScrollView = new UIScrollView();

    panelScrollView.CanCancelContentTouches=false;
    panelScrollView.ClipsToBounds = true; 

    panelScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    panelScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
    panelScrollView.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
    //panelScrollView.Delegate = this;

    panelScrollView.BackgroundColor=UIColor.Black;
    if (page == 1)
    {
        panelScrollView.BackgroundColor=UIColor.Red;
    }

    panelScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
    panelScrollView.UserInteractionEnabled=true;
    var ui = new UIImage (_assetImages[page], 1.0f, UIImageOrientation.Up);

    //UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(new RectangleF(100,100,1000,1000));
    //imgView.Image = ui;

    UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(ui);

    panelScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(imgView.Frame.Size.Width, imgView.Frame.Size.Height);

    //Position the panelScrollView in the right page on the main scrollview
    RectangleF frame = scrollView.Frame;
    PointF location = new PointF();
    location.X = frame.Width * (_numberOfPanels - 1);
    frame.Location = location;

    panelScrollView.Frame = frame;
    //panelScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(1000,1000);
    panelScrollView.BackgroundColor=UIColor.Green;
    /*imgView.Frame = new RectangleF(panelScrollView.Frame.Width /2,
                                   panelScrollView.Frame.Height/2,
                                   imgView.Frame.Width,
                                   imgView.Frame.Height);*/
    imgView.Center = new PointF(panelScrollView.Frame.Width /2,
                                panelScrollView.Frame.Height/2);


    imgView.ContentMode=UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;

    //panelScrollView.ContentSize = panelScrollView.Bounds.Size;


    panelScrollView.ZoomingStarted += (object sender, UIScrollViewZoomingEventArgs e) => 
    {
        int x;
    };

    panelScrollView.DidZoom += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        //ScrollViewDidZoom handler
        //handle zooming and positioning of the panel scroll view (aka, scrollview of the image)
        var innerFrame = imgView.Frame;
        var scrollerBounds = panelScrollView.Bounds;

        if ( ( innerFrame.Size.Width < scrollerBounds.Size.Width ) || ( innerFrame.Size.Height < scrollerBounds.Size.Height ) )
        {
            var x = imgView.Center.X - ( scrollerBounds.Size.Width / 2 );
            var y = imgView.Center.Y - ( scrollerBounds.Size.Height / 2 );
            PointF myScrollViewOffset = new PointF(x, y);

            panelScrollView.ContentOffset = myScrollViewOffset;

        }

        UIEdgeInsets anEdgeInset =  new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if ( scrollerBounds.Size.Width > innerFrame.Size.Width )
        {
            anEdgeInset.Left = (scrollerBounds.Size.Width - innerFrame.Size.Width) / 2;
            anEdgeInset.Right = -anEdgeInset.Left;  // I don't know why this needs to be negative, but that's what works
        }
        if ( scrollerBounds.Size.Height > innerFrame.Size.Height )
        {
            anEdgeInset.Top = (scrollerBounds.Size.Height - innerFrame.Size.Height) / 2;
            anEdgeInset.Bottom = -anEdgeInset.Top;  // I don't know why this needs to be negative, but that's what works
        }
        panelScrollView.ContentInset = anEdgeInset;

};

panelScrollView.AddSubview(imgView);
scrollView.AddSubview(panelScrollView);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting zooming event by touching image itself then by default user interaction is disabled for a imageview. Set "imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES"
Or if the zooming event is coming from any delegate method, (in your case may be delegate of UIScrollView), then add a delegate listener like "panelScrollView.delegate = self"

I think delegate implementation should be in following way.

Mention in code this line , panelScrollView.delegate = self; and add following methods in self class. If you get any warning for UIScrollViewDelegate is not defined then add **UIScrollViewDelegate** in your header file.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view
{
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
}
```

After adding this code, delegate method should be get called.

Comment: I believe this is all I need in MonoTouch to set the Zooming delegate.. panelScrollView.DidZoom += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { ..etc
This basically says the following block of code is the delegate for ScrollDidZoom.  Now, do I still need to set delegate property like you mention?  I don't know what it's for.

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT.  I just needed to add this:
   panelScrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { 
    return imgView; 
   };